# PowerPoint PPS opens as PPT

Tags: 2010, powerpoint

Im trying to get a PPS file to open in PowerPoint as a PPS. However, depending on a few things it may open as PPT.

If Client Integration is off, it opens as a PPT. If Client Integration is On, it will open as a PPS, but only if you open it from the document library or a web part exposing the library. If Client Integration is on and you link to it from a page (Content Editor) it will open as PPT.

Ideally i would like to control that last issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i dont fully understand the implications, it turned out it was a registry setting on the client

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPoint.Show.8

The BrowserFlag value can be one of the following:

a = Open in PowerPoint (Seems to be default in Win7)
8 = Open full screen as show
0 or non-existent key = Open as show in a browser window (seems to be default in XP)